# Проблема с чтением из текстового файла не txt формата

Tags: c++, qt

Есть примерно такой код:

```
QString path;//Чем-то там инициализируется
QFile file;
file.setFileName(path);
file.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite | QIODevice::Text)
QTextStream fstream(&file);
qDebug() << file.readAll() << fstream.readLine();
```

Если файл в расширении .txt то все ок. Если файл в расширении .dtb то выводятся две пустые строки, хотя формально содержимое файлов одинаково. Что с этим можно сделать? У моего друга, который не на qt-шном c++ пишет, все в этом плане нормально. Мне нужно все тоже на обычные плюсы переписать?

Comment: по идее проблем не должно быть может проблема в путях к файлу или русским буквам или что-то еще, qt по сути тот же с++ только со своими классами насколько я знаю, можно попробовать переписать на с++ и проверить

Comment: Попробуйте убрать опцию QIODevice::Text

Comment: "хотя формально содержимое файлов одинаково" такого не бывает. оно либо одинаковое либо нет.

Comment: Окей, если открывать файлы в Блокноте, то их содержимое идентично

Answer (score 0):

Короче, у меня тут 100500 багов в коде, но все они появляются и пропадают как-то сами по себе, так что, в некотором смысле, проблема решена. Можно удалить файл из папки руками, потом сделать remove() в коде, потому что для Qt этот файл почему-то еще существует и даже открывается, затем вернуть файл на место. И тогда читается любой формат. Да, дело не в формате